# Docker install Nodejs giving error engine Unsupported engine

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, ubuntu, npm

I have a docker which install nodejs and npm. It used to work fine previously but since today it has stared to crash with following error.

```
------
 > [assets 4/9] RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y         nodejs     && npm i npm@latest -g:
#8 67.38 Setting up nodejs (16.20.2-deb-1nodesource1) ...
#8 67.82 npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
#8 67.82 npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
#8 67.82 npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.0.0
#8 67.82 npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.0.0
#8 67.82 npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
#8 67.82 npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.19.4","node":"v16.20.2"} 
#8 67.82 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#8 67.82 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-01T07_07_39_330Z-debug-0.log
------
```

Docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV TMPDIR=/tmp

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        software-properties-common \
        bzip2 \
        git

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt-get install -y \
        firefox \
        chromium-browser

# Install Node
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y \
        nodejs \
    && npm i npm@latest -g

ENV CHROMIUM_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

RUN rm -rf /app/*

COPY ./code/ /app/
WORKDIR /app

RUN rm -rf node_modules \
    && rm -rf ./static/vendor

RUN npm ci --legacy-peer-deps
```

I also see some warning related to installation of nodejs command.

```
#0 0.297 ================================================================================
#0 0.297 ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
#0 0.297 ================================================================================
#0 0.297 
#0 0.297                            SCRIPT DEPRECATION WARNING                    
#0 0.297 
#0 0.297   
#0 0.297   This script, located at https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_X, used to
#0 0.297   install Node.js is deprecated now and will eventually be made inactive.
#0 0.297 
#0 0.297   Please visit the NodeSource distributions Github and follow the
#0 0.297   instructions to migrate your repo.
#0 0.297   https://github.com/nodesource/distributions
#0 0.297 
#0 0.297   The NodeSource Node.js Linux distributions GitHub repository contains
#0 0.297   information about which versions of Node.js and which Linux distributions
#0 0.297   are supported and how to install it.
#0 0.297   https://github.com/nodesource/distributions
#0 0.297 
#0 0.297 
#0 0.297                           SCRIPT DEPRECATION WARNING
#0 0.297 
#0 0.297 ================================================================================
#0 0.297 ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
#0 0.297 ================================================================================
```

So what is the other best way to insatll Nodejs with docker.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be caused by an npm 10 release

https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.0.0

> support for node 14 and 16 has been dropped. npm now supports node ^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0

Try installing npm 9 in your Dockerfile instead:

```
npm i npm@9 -g
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed all of our problems. Going to be going in later to change the install process like the `Script Deprecation Warning` suggests.

Comment: Thanks this solves the issues, any detailed explanations for inexperienced like me, please?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the working solution:

```
# set verions of using packages
ARG NODE_VERSION=18 # NodeJS
# install NodeJS
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install -yq ca-certificates curl gnupg \
    && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings \
    && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_VERSION.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list \
    && apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq \
    && npm install -g npm

** make here all what you need with Node **

# uninstall NodeJS
RUN apt-get purge nodejs -yq \
    && apt autoremove -yq \
    && rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list \
    && rm -r /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
# cleanup
RUN fc-cache -f -v \
    && apt-get -qq clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Based on [nodesource installation-instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions).

Answer (score 1):

We can use image created instead of building it from scratch.

```
FROM node:lts
RUN rm -rf /app/*

COPY ./code/ /app/
WORKDIR /app

RUN rm -rf node_modules \
    && rm -rf ./static/vendor

RUN npm ci --legacy-peer-deps
```

Please refer to https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp

Comment: your solution will not work if I need to use another base image, `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet` for example. Or is there a way to merge two base images?

Comment: I do not understand why a nodejs project will use dotnet. If they are two project, it will be better to build seperately. Anyway, we can have two base in a docker file. Please refer to this https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/multi-stage/

Comment: Its common to have ASP.NET projects that do serverside node things (e.g react serverside rendering, SSR). There, you could have one stage that builds/bundles your client app. But another stage is ASP and it delivers the bundle, but it also does SSR to be SEO optimized. This SSR needs a ASP.NET->Node bridge